# Search query suggestions are not working in the compact search box

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

Has anyone run into the issue of trying to display query suggestions in the small compact search box in the header?  I am able to get the large search box on a search page to display query suggestions.  However, the small search box in the header does not show any query suggestions.  Settings are enabled such as "ShowQuerySuggestions=true".  The following image is what I am trying to replicate with the compact search box. Any help is greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I have done further testing and here are my findings:

1. In a specific site collection when performing search make sure searching against that site by selecting 'This Site' in the drop-down
2. Click the search result/s more than SIX times so that query text is added as a suggestion word/phrase
3. On the results page verify that in url 'u' parameter value is pointing to this site url. 
   i.e. ...osssearchresults.aspx?u=https://contoso.sharepoint.com&k=querytext

By following above making sure that Search suggestion are added against this site and will show up in all search boxes.